# Merge and remove remote branch in git

Tags: git

I imported the trunk and a branch from svn to git using `git-svn`. I've got them both in git but the branch stands by itself and does not point towards the trunk. Here is how it looks graphically:

```
a<--b<--c<--d
         \    \
          \    (master)(remotes/trunk)
           \
            (remotes/feature1)

a<--b<--c<--d<--e
                 \
                  (remotes/branches/feature1)
```

What I want is to have remotes/branches/feature1 merged to remotes/feature1 and delete remotes/branches/feature1 so that it would be:

```
 a<--b<--c<--d
         ^    \
          \    (master)(remotes/trunk)
           \
            e' (remotes/feature1)
```

How do I accomplish this? I searched quite a bit but have not got the result that I wanted.

Comment: I don't know how git-svn works.  Do you have two repositories, where "master" refers to a local branch and "remotes/feature1" refers to a reference from a remote?  Or are they all local branches?

Comment: This is in the same local repository after git-svn did the import. branches with remotes prefix are listed as remote branches and can be listed using `git branch -r`.

Comment: ok - and when you say 'delete remotes/branches/feature1' you mean just the reference in this repository, and note the reference on the actual remote?  I'll presume that

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in your second graph you would end up with e' not e.  Any time you change parentage you get a new sha even if the content introduced is the same.

I'm guessing you are just fudging things in the local repo, and don't need to make the changes upstream?  If that's the case then you could cherry pick to move the sha, the do some forced updates on the branch pointers.

```
git checkout -b new_feature1
git cherry-pick e
git update-ref remotes/feature1 HEAD
git update-ref -d remotes/branches/feature1
```

If you actually need to make the changes on the remote then you would definitely not want to do the update-ref. You'd have to do `git push -f new_feature1:feature1` and `git push --delete` instead.

Comment: I used cherry picking.